# Could not find an overload for "init" that accepts the supplied arguments (swift)

Tags: swift

I have defined the webservice URL:

```
 let  getLoginURL = "http://example-web-service.com"
```

then passed this url via NSURL and assigned to the variable called "url".

```
 let url = NSURL(getLoginURL)
```

I am getting the "Could not fin an overload for "init" that accepts the supplied arguments" error.

What would be the reason?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide the string parameter name when you initialize NSURL

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://example-web-service.com")
```

Comment: Yes I got it up to : let url:NSURL but did not initialise it.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error:
let getLoginUrl:NSURL = NSURL (string: "example url.com")
let url:NSURL = NSURL(getLoginURL)

Comment: You've already initialized the NSURL for getLoginUrl parameter and are trying to initialize a new NSURL instance with it. Simply use the getLoginUrl now

Comment: what computed variable and Double convert same error